# Wordpress. Donations для каждого пользователя

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть множество плагинов, которые позволяют собирать средства на сайте. Но мне нужно, чтобы каждый зарегистрированный пользователь мог создавать свою форму для доната. GiveWP пробовал, отличный, но там такой функции нет. Смотрел на другие, там тоже самое, но проблема остаётся та же.

Может кто-то подскажет, что можно использовать для такой задачи?

Comment: Что значит свою форму для доната? Это не просто инпут добавить.. Вряд ли найдёте такой плагин

Comment: @InDevX Я понимаю, что не просто добавить. Поэтому и спрашиваю, т.к. потратил много времени, чтобы найти хотя бы какой-то намёк на подобное решение. Но такого нет